# DateTime String to Date, In Time and Out Time

Tags: mysql, sql, string, datetime, format

I have attendance record table like this

```
+----------------+---------+-----------------------+
| NIP            | Nama    | Date_Time             |
+----------------+---------+-----------------------+
| 050803075201   | Supomo  | 2013-02-20 07:45:57   | 
| 050803075201   | Supomo  | 2013-02-20 17:24:13   | 
| 050803075201   | Supomo  | 2013-02-21 07:53:40   | 
| 050803075201   | Supomo  | 2013-02-21 17:31:57   | 
| 050803075200   | Teguh   | 2013-02-21 20:31:02   | 
| 050803075200   | Teguh   | 2013-02-20 18:18:07   | 
+----------------+---------+-----------------------+
```

`Date_Time` is in string format.

And then I want to make it like this table:

```
+----------------+---------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| NIP            | Nama    | Date        | In          | Out         |
+----------------+---------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 050803075200   | Teguh   | 2013-02-21  |             | 18:18:07    |
| 050803075200   | Teguh   | 2013-02-20  |             | 20:31:02    | 
| 050803075201   | Supomo  | 2013-02-20  | 07:45:57    | 17:24:13    | 
| 050803075201   | Supomo  | 2013-02-21  | 07:53:40    | 17:31:57    |
+----------------+---------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

What query will do this?

Comment: What determines if a time is "in" or "out"? It's also helpful to post what you've tried. It's also more likely to get more answers if you show some effort, instead of simply asking for code. And don't forget, make it absolutely clear, how your table gets transformed into your desired result.

Comment: yeah sorry about that, after this post, i will post what i've tried. Thanks for your suggestion. Cheers :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Here is the SQLFiddel Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/15937/2)**

**Below is the Query**

```
select NIP,
       Nama,
       DATE_FORMAT(Date_Time, '%Y-%m-%d') as date,
       Case Min(Date_Time) 
         When Max(Date_Time) 
          Then '' 
         Else DATE_FORMAT(Date_Time, '%H:%i:%s') 
       End as InTime,

       DATE_FORMAT(max(Date_Time), '%H:%i:%s') as OutTime
  from Attd
 Group By NIP,
       Nama,
       DATE_FORMAT(Date_Time, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: Sorry for late respons Roms. I have just opened the internet. It's very great thanks. But in my code it's not running. After I tracing in my code, this database is microsoft access. I have manipulate your code into ms access but still not working. I hope you can help me roms. this Here Is my query in SQLFiddle:(http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ba128/10)