# replacing (Date_format,Case) in MySQL format into (Format,IIF) in ms-access format

Tags: mysql, ms-access, datetime, case, date-format

I have two table like this

1.HR_Personnel

```
+-----+---------------+--------+
| ID  | NIP           | Name   |
+---------------------+--------+
| 1   | 050803075200  | Teguh  | 
| 2   | 050803075201  | Supomo | 
+-----+---------------+--------+
```

2.TA_Record_Info

```
+-----+-----+---------+-----------------------+
| NIP | NIP | Nama    | Date_Time             |
+-----+-----+---------+-----------------------+
| 2   | 2   | Supomo  | 2013-02-20 07:45:57   | 
| 2   | 2   | Supomo  | 2013-02-20 17:24:13   | 
| 1   | 1   | Supomo  | 2013-02-20 18:18:07   | 
| 2   | 2   | Supomo  | 2013-02-21 07:53:40   | 
| 2   | 2   | Teguh   | 2013-02-21 20:31:02   | 
| 1   | 1   | Teguh   | 2013-02-21 17:31:57   | 
+-----+-----+---------+-----------------------+
```

`Date_Time` is in string format.

And then I want to make it like this table:

```
+----------------+---------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| NIP            | Nama    | Date        | In          | Out         |
+----------------+---------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 050803075200   | Teguh   | 2013-02-21  |             | 18:18:07    |
| 050803075200   | Teguh   | 2013-02-20  |             | 20:31:02    | 
| 050803075201   | Supomo  | 2013-02-20  | 07:45:57    | 17:24:13    | 
| 050803075201   | Supomo  | 2013-02-21  | 07:53:40    | 17:31:57    |
+----------------+---------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

I have Try in MySQL Query based on the answer my previous question [DateTime String to Date, In Time and Out Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18227191/datetime-string-to-date-in-time-and-out-time?noredirect=1#comment26725606_18227191). It's successfull. this is query code:

```
SELECT p.Per_Code as NIP,
   p.Per_Name as Nama,
   DATE_FORMAT(a.Date_Time, '%Y-%m-%d') as date,
   Case Min(a.Date_Time)
    When Max(a.Date_Time) 
     Then '' 
     Else DATE_FORMAT(a.Date_Time, '%H:%i:%s') 
   End as InTime,
   DATE_FORMAT(max(a.Date_Time), '%H:%i:%s') as OutTime
FROM  HR_Personnel as p
RIGHT JOIN  TA_Record_Info a
ON p.ID=a.Per_ID
Group By NIP,
     Nama,
     DATE_FORMAT(Date_Time, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

You can see MYSQL Query Testing [in Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/96daa/1)

And then I have try it in ms Access but still Not Working. This is the query code:

```
SELECT p.Per_Code AS NIP,
   p.Per_Name AS Nama,
   Format (a.Date_Time, "yyyy-mm-dd") as date,
   IIF(
       (Min(a.Date_Time) = Max(a.Date_Time)) ,
        '',
        Format (a.Date_Time, "hh/mm/ss")
   )as InTime,
   Format (Max(a.Date_Time), "hh/mm/ss") AS OutTime 
FROM HR_Personnel AS p 
RIGHT JOIN TA_Record_Info a 
ON p.ID=a.Per_ID 
GROUP BY p.Per_Code,
         p.Per_Name,
         Format (a.Date_Time, "yyyy-mm-dd")
```

I have try that in my PDO:Querry but still show error message:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch()

I don't know how testing in ms-access. I just know `PHP and MySql`. I use `ms-access` database because my Information system connected with a fingerprint that only have ms-access database.
What must i do to solve this problem?

Comment: Hi HansUp I 've found the solution of my problem. Thanks for your respons. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem has solve. The Query must be like this:

```
SELECT p.Per_Code AS NIP,
       p.Per_Name AS Nama,
       Format (a.Date_Time, "yyyy-mm-dd") as date,
       IIF(
           (Min(a.Date_Time) = Max(a.Date_Time)) ,
           '',
           Format (Min(a.Date_Time), "hh/mm/ss")
       )as InTime,
       Format (Max(a.Date_Time), "hh/mm/ss") AS OutTime
FROM HR_Personnel AS p 
RIGHT JOIN TA_Record_Info a 
ON p.ID=a.Per_ID 
GROUP BY p.Per_Code,
     p.Per_Name,
     Format (a.Date_Time, "yyyy-mm-dd")
```

The error lies in Line 7.
previous query like this:

> Format (a.Date_Time, "hh/mm/ss")

then changed like this:

> Format (Min(a.Date_Time), "hh/mm/ss")

I think the error arise because `a.Date_Time` not recognized by ms-access.

Finnally,Thanks to HansUp which has continued to respond to my question. Cheers :D